# Ubuntu/PHP/Nginx - Sessions expiring instantly

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-18.04

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server that used to run Apache and PHP 7.4. I have recently changed from Apache to Nginx and as a result PHP sessions now expire instantly.

Some actions that I have already taken:

1. I have removed the CRON which deletes sessions.
2. I have updated the php.ini to reflect much longer expiration times.
3. I have changed the directory of sessions being saved.

My current php.ini values are:

```
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/sessionsnew"
session.cookie_lifetime = 86400
session.gc_maxlifetime = 86400
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you sure you edited the correct php.ini file? You can check the correct path of the file by creating a PHP file with `<?php phpinfo();` and running it (from your browser, via nginx).

Comment: Yes, it's definitely the right file.